# Azure Cosmos DB SQL API QueryDefinition multiple parameters for WHERE IN

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to use SQL query parameters with a `WHERE ... IN` statement in an Azure Cosmos DB SQL API query:

```cs
var componentDesignGuids = new List<Guid>();
// ...
var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(
        "SELECT componentDesign.guid, componentDesign.component.name, componentDesign.component.componentType " +
        "FROM components componentDesign " +
        "WHERE componentDesign.guid IN (@componentDesignGuids)")
    .WithParameter("@componentDesignGuids", string.Join(",", componentDesignGuids.Select(guid => $"\"{guid}\""))));
```

but this results in a query where the replaced parameter is a single string, like `IN ("guid0, guid1, guid2")`. Since this is an `IN` clause, I want to put an indeterminate number of strings there, like `IN ("\"guid0\", \"guid1\", \"guid2\"")`. I realize I can make this work with an interpolated string, but I want to be as safe with inputs as possible to prevent injection. How can I specify this with `QueryDefinition` and/or `WithParameter`?

Comment: this is a valid question and not a dup. The answer is any IN query can be written as ARRAY_CONTAINS, which can be parameterized.

Comment: Any updates here? Im facing the same problem :/

Comment: @Frank I ended up generating a parameter for each item in my list and then filling in each of those generated parameters with `.WithParameter`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you @ScottyH i'll try that. I hope they fix this soon