# Parameterized Where IN clause does not work with CosmosClient QueryDefinition Object

Tags: c#, .net, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**I am trying to write a parameterized query that has IN clause.**

For Ex :

**Working code**

Input string : "'guid1','guid2','guid3'"

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeIds(string ids){
QueryDefinition query =new QueryDefinition(@"Select * from Employee where Employee.Id in ("+ ids+")");
var result = GetDetails(query,cosmosClient);
return result;
}
```

Result: It returns the expected result

**Non-working code**

Input string : "'guid1','guid2','guid3'"

```
public List<Employee> GetEmployeeIds(string ids){
QueryDefinition query =new QueryDefinition(@"Select * from Employee where Employee.Id in ( @ids )")
                  .WithParameter("@ids", ids);
var result = GetDetails(query,cosmosClient);
return result;
}
```

Result: It returns 0

**NuGet** package used for above code: **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.8.0**

**Note:** I have tried all the options which are mentioned in this link but it does not work with CosmosClient QueryDefinition Object
[WHERE IN with Azure DocumentDB (CosmosDB) .Net SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636971/where-in-with-azure-documentdb-cosmosdb-net-sdk/70878141#70878141)

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: This is answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70136568/cosmos-db-net-sdk-order-by-a-dynamic-field-parameterized/70138266#70138266

Answer (score 10):

This is working for me, where `@ids` is a list type, and instead of using the `IN` keyword I use the `ARRAY_CONTAINS` function:

```
List<long> ids = new List<long>();
ids.Add(712300002201);
ids.Add(712300002234);

var querySql = @"Select * from Employee where ARRAY_CONTAINS(@ids, Employee.Id)";
var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@ids", ids);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that your `ids` value is something like `"12,42,94,7"`. As a string parameter `@ids`, the expression `in (@ids)` is broadly the same as `in ('12,42,94,7'`), which won't match any values, if the values are the *individual* numbers `12`, `42`, `94` and `7`. When you used the simple contatenated version, the meaning was different - i.e. `in (12,42,94,7)` (note the lack of quotes), which is 4 integer values, not 1 string value.

Basically: when parameterizing this, you would need to *either*

1. use multiple parameters, one per value, i.e. ending up with `in (@ids0, @ids1, @ids2, @ids3)` with 4 parameter values (either by splitting the string in the C# code, or using a different parameter type - perhaps `params int[] ids`)
2. use a function like the `STRING_SPLIT` SQL Server function, if similar exists for CosmosDB - i.e. `in (select value from STRING_SPLIT(@ids,','))`

Comment: Hi Marc, Thank you for your reply..!! I tried this option but seems does not work with the QueryDefinition object of CosmosClient.

Comment: @RahulC which? I gave two suggestions; which did you try?

Comment: Hi have tried the first suggestion and the second STRING_SPLIT does not exist for CosmosDB

Comment: Apologies, the first suggestion worked, I was passing the wrong string values with multiple parameters. Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried looking into the question asked below.

[Azure Cosmos DB SQL API QueryDefinition multiple parameters for WHERE IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58191745/azure-cosmos-db-sql-api-querydefinition-multiple-parameters-for-where-in?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I think ids are being treated as a single string therefore the results are not returning.

Alternatively, you could try using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core package and make use of Document Client to write LINQ queries like in the code snippet below.

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(CosmosDbEndpoint), PrimaryKeyCosmosDB)){

            List<MyClass> obj= client.CreateDocumentQuery<List<MyClass>>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseName, collectionName))
                    .Where(r => ids.Contains(r.id))
                    .AsEnumerable();}
```

Comment: Hi Ramee, Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core package is deprecated now.